# Is there a universal method to create a tail recursive function in Scala?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

While checking Intel's BigDL [repo](https://github.com/intel-analytics/BigDL/blob/master/visualization/src/main/scala/com/intel/analytics/bigdl/visualization/tensorboard/FileReader.scala), I stumbled upon this method:

```
private def recursiveListFiles(f: java.io.File, r: Regex): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles()
  val good = these.filter(f => r.findFirstIn(f.getName).isDefined)
  good ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles(_, r))
}
```

I noticed that it was not tail recursive and decided to write a tail recursive version:

```
private def recursiveListFiles(f: File, r: Regex): Array[File] = {
@scala.annotation.tailrec def recursiveListFiles0(f: Array[File], r: Regex, a: Array[File]): Array[File] = {
  f match {
    case Array() => a
    case htail => {
      val these = htail.head.listFiles()
      val good = these.filter(f => r.findFirstIn(f.getName).isDefined)
      recursiveListFiles0(these.filter(_.isDirectory)++htail.tail, r, a ++ good)
    }
  }
}
recursiveListFiles0(Array[File](f), r, Array.empty[File])
}
```

What made this difficult compared to what I am used to is the concept that a File can be transformed into an Array[File] which adds another level of depth.

**What is the theory behind recursion on datatypes that have the following member?**

```
def listTs[T]: T => Traversable[T]
```

Comment: Your `f` parameter is essentially a *stack* of to-be-processed items. I don't think there is anything special with your datatype, this is just the standard way to make *any* recursive function a loop (or tail-recursive).

Comment: Take a look at the concepts of `cofree monad` and `trampoline` in functional programming (you'll find good articles in Scala, Haskell, Lisp, etc.)

Comment: Closest I can think of to a "theory behind recursion on data types" is presented  around this work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%E2%80%93Meertens_formalism and also the derived famous "Functional programming with bananas, lenses, envelopes and barbed wire".

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari Any seminal papers on trampolines?

Comment: Adding to my first comment. Follow the wikipedia "See also" links in Ana- and Catamorphism.

Comment: @pedrofurla see my answer below, sorry if it's not really complete but it takes pages to describe Free, Cofree, Trampoline, etc. Hope the references help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

If you generalize the idea and think of it as a monad (polymorphic thing working for arbitrary type params) then you won't be able to implement a tail recursive implementation.

Trampolines try to solve this very problem by providing a way to evaluate a recursive computation without overflowing the stack. The general idea is to create a stream of pairs of (result, computation). So at each step you'll have to return the computed result up to that point and a function to create the next result (aka `thunk`).

From Rich Dougherty’s blog:

> A trampoline is a loop that repeatedly runs functions. Each function,
>   called a thunk, returns the next function for the loop to run. The
>   trampoline never runs more than one thunk at a time, so if you break
>   up your program into small enough thunks and bounce each one off the
>   trampoline, then you can be sure the stack won't grow too big.

### More + References

In the categorical sense, the theory behind such data types is closely related to `Cofree Monads` and `fold` and `unfold` functions, and in general to `Fixed point types`.

See this fantastic talk: [Fun and Games with Fix Cofree and Doobie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qibEWE3Oe2M&list=PL-ziwLLJ3XaLspsk9o7gQJB5oZtqS43Qu&index=8) by Rob Norris which discusses a use case very similar to your question.

This article about Free monads and Trampolines is also related to your first question: [Stackless Scala With Free Monads](http://days2012.scala-lang.org/sites/days2012/files/bjarnason_trampolines.pdf).

See also this part of the [Matryoshka docs](https://github.com/slamdata/matryoshka#unfolds). [Matryoshka](https://github.com/slamdata/matryoshka) is a Scala library implementing monads around the concept of FixedPoint types.

Comment: @Haykel Talbi Since you asked `if a theory exists` behind this family of recursive data types, I just briefly mentioned the related monads and concepts. You can always ask for more details :)

Comment: Thank you for this valuable answer @NaderHadjiGhanbari. The Rob Norris and Greg Pfeil talk, as well as the Bjarnason paper helped getting a basic understanding of the Cofree comonad and Fix. It was interesting to learn that neither Scalaz nor Cats had an implementation of Fix. I still have a lot of reading to do. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: I failed to mention that there are two high-level concepts (high-level as in their categorical sense) related to Free and Cofree monads, namely `Anamorphism` and `Catamorphism` (correpsonding to unfold and fold) and their composition (cata after ana), namely `Hylomorphism`.